# Converting an image pixel from color ARGB to grayscale ARGB manually

Tags: java, algorithm, grayscale, argb

So I've got a project to convert an image to black and white manually by altering the argb values with an algorithm.  I've tried averaging the RGB values and I come out with an almost completely grayscale image but there's still hints of color in it. Anyone have any algorithm examples to convert a pixel in aRGB to greyscale manually?

This is what I've been doing so far:

```
            //Apply the filter
            reds = ((reds+greens+blues)/3);
            greens = ((reds+greens+blues)/3);
            blues = ((reds+greens+blues)/3);
```

Comment: Worth noting that due to the biology of the human eye, red, green, and blue should not be evenly weighted when an image is converted to grayscale.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're changing the inputs of the Right Hand Side while expecting its value to remain constant. Why not use this?

```
reds = (reds + greens + blues) / 3;
greens = reds;
blues = reds;
```

Comment: @user1088595 don't feel bad, I just mixed up left and right :)

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to mark this answer as correct.

Answer (score 4):

I've always been under the impression that, due to our eyes' differing sensitivities to red, green and blue wavelengths, grayscale should be computed using:

```
(int) (0.299 * red + 0.587 * green + 0.114 * blue)
```

Years ago, this used to be easy information to find, but now I can't find too many sources for it.  [Wikipedia's entry on grayscale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale) is one.